# Mocking Promises makes them return undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I'm trying to run some jest tests on my React components, more specifically for my LoginForm component.

I have a function that calls the auth api for login:

```
import axios from 'axios'

const doLogin = (username: string, password: string) => {
  return axios.post('api/auth', {
    username,
    password
  })
}

export default { doLogin }
```

Pretty simple, just returns a Promise of the axios response.

And I've implemented it in my `LoginPage.tsx`: (**submitLogin**):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import SwitchLogo from '../assets/switch-logo.png'
import { Button, TextBox } from '../components/Form'
import userApi from '../api/user'

const LoginPage = () => {
  const { doLogin } = userApi
  const [username, setUsername] = useState<string>('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState<string>('')

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false)
  const [error, setError] = useState<string | undefined>(undefined)

  const onUsernameChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setUsername(e.currentTarget.value)
  }

  const onPasswordChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setPassword(e.currentTarget.value)
  }

  const onSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (!username || !password) {
      setError('Please fill in login details.')
      return
    }
    submitLogin()
  }

  const submitLogin = () => {
    setError(undefined)
    setLoading(true)
    doLogin(username, password).then((response) => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(response))
    }).catch((err) => {
      setError(err.response.data.error)
    }).finally(() => setLoading(false))
  }

  return (
    <div className="flex h-screen bg-gray-50">
      <div className="m-auto w-full sm:w-5/6 lg:w-2/4 xl:w-1/3">
        <div className="flex justify-center"><img src={SwitchLogo} className="w-32 h-32" alt="switch-logo" /></div>
        <form onSubmit={onSubmit} data-testid='form'>
          <div className="bg-white shadow-lg drop-shadow-lg rounded px-8 pt-6 pb-8 mb-4 flex flex-col gap-4">
            <div className='flex flex-col gap-2 text-center'>
              <p className="text-4xl font-bold">Sign in</p>
              <p className='text-sm'>Please sign in to access all features.</p>
            </div>
            <div className="divider m-0" />
            <div>
              <TextBox id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" required value={username} onChange={onUsernameChange} data-testid='username' />
            </div>
            <div>
              <TextBox id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" required value={password} onChange={onPasswordChange} data-testid='password' />
            </div>
            <Button colour='red' loading={loading} data-testid='submit'>{!loading && 'Sign in'}</Button>
            <Button colour='sky' type='button' outline><Link to='/register'>Register new account</Link></Button>
          </div>
          {error && (<div className="alert alert-error">
            <div className='mx-auto'>
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" className="w-6 h-6 mx-2 stroke-current">
                <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="2" d="M18.364 18.364A9 9 0 005.636 5.636m12.728 12.728A9 9 0 015.636 5.636m12.728 12.728L5.636 5.636"></path>
              </svg>
              <label>{error}</label>
            </div>
          </div>)}
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default LoginPage
```

Notice that `doLogin` is called and then is handled with a `.then`. This all works fine when I run the app.

The issue is when I'm trying to test my login page.

I have my spec file for the login page, where I am mocking the `post` function inside axios, and then returning a basic `AxiosResponse` object with minimal data (`LoginPage.spec.tsx`):

```
import { fireEvent, getByTestId, getByText, render } from '@testing-library/react'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import LoginPage from './LoginPage'
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from 'axios'

jest.mock('axios')

const mockedAxios = axios as jest.Mocked<typeof axios>

const base: AxiosResponse<any, any> = {
  data: { test: 123 },
  status: 200,
  statusText: 'OK',
  headers: {},
  config: {}
}

mockedAxios.post.mockResolvedValue(base)

describe('Sign in form', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    render(
      <BrowserRouter>
        <LoginPage />
      </BrowserRouter >
    )
  })

  it('Renders', () => {
    expect(getByText(document.body, /Please sign in to access all features./i)).toBeInTheDocument()
  })

  it('Does not submit when no data filled in', () => {
    fireEvent.click(getByTestId(document.body, 'submit'))
    expect(getByText(document.body, /Please fill in login details/i)).toBeInTheDocument()
    expect(mockedAxios.post).not.toHaveBeenCalled()
  })

  it('Submits when data filled in', () => {
    fireEvent.change(getByTestId(document.body, 'username'), { target: { value: 'testUser' } })
    fireEvent.change(getByTestId(document.body, 'password'), { target: { value: 'testPassword' } })
    fireEvent.click(getByTestId(document.body, 'submit'))
    expect(mockedAxios.post).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
  })
})
```

What happens is that when the test runs, it calls `submitLogin`, then tries to call `doLogin().then`, but apparently the `.then` doesn't exist:

> Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')]

Comment: Just make sure that `doLogin` returns an object with a then method. https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks might help

Comment: @evolutionxbox I don't understand. It does. A promise should contain a `.then` method, which is what doLogin is returning... a Promise.

Comment: Not according to the error. It thinks that `doLogin` is returning undefined.

Comment: Yeah I know, I just don't understand why. I've been scratching my head for hours.

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured it out. The issue is because I'm mocking the function outside of the tests, but then after each test, jest resets the mocks - meaning my functions were no longer being mocked. I simply just had to place `mockedAxios.post.mockResolvedValue(base)` into the `beforeEach` block.